# Parsley.js: date input field is not validated when clicking (x)

Tags: parsley.js

I have noticed that my custom validator is not called, if i click the (x) and clearing the field. Is this some kind of mistake or missing configuration on my side? Or is this a bug in parsley?

Parsley is used, because i run a typo3 project using powermail wihich comes with parsley 2.7.2. (I used 2.9 shortly, but i got the same behaviour)

```
<form data-parsley-validate>
  <input type="date" value="validate" data-parsley-test="test" data-parsley-trigger="change">
  <p id="changeOutput"></p>
  <p id="addValidatorOutput"></p>
</form>
<button onclick="$('form').parsley().destroy();">destroy</button>

<script>
$(function () {
  var name = $('form').parsley();

  $("[type=date]").change(function() {
         $("#changeOutput").html('change:'+Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
    });

});

window.Parsley
  .addValidator('test', {
    requirementType: 'string',
    validateString: function(value, requirement) {

        $("#addValidatorOutput").html('addValidator:'+Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
        return true;
    }
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsley will not (by default) validate empty fields. You are can add the `data-parsley-validate-if-empty` attribute and your validator will run even when the user clicks on the "x".